# Can't deploy asp.net web api debug mode on azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, azure, deployment

I have a asp.net web api application. It works completely well.
I deployed it on an azure web app (with right click -> publish...). I can get my token with the url xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/Token but when I call an url xxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/xxxx, it returns an error 500.
So I wanted to remote debug my application, I tried to deploy with "Configuration : Debug" but when I do it, I have the error :

```
Error   5   Web deployment task failed. (Création d'une application qui n'est pas prise en charge par cet environnement serveur.
  Pour en savoir plus : http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED.)     0   0   Api
```

Sorry, it's a french error (translation : Creation of an application which is not supported by this server environment. To see more :).

Is there anyone who knows how to deploy in debug ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salut!  I'm not sure about that specific error but remote debugging requires attaching the debugger.  Take a look at this Microsoft article describing how to set Visual Studio for remote debugging Azure Web sites.

https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/05/06/introduction-to-remote-debugging-on-azure-web-sites/

Comment: That's why I love stackoverflow...Thank you very much. It worked, I configured myself the publish settings and it worked only for release deployment. But with that "Download the publish profile" and import, it worked !